# Script not consistently running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script that needs to run at the end of the relevant day, I have tried to get it to run on a timer and I can't work it out. I have 5 sheets which are for different parts of the day to schedule the staff.  At the end of the day I need to send it to a master sheet that tallies hours worked and various tasks worked on.  My issues are:-
1) I have a blank Google Worksheet with 5 sheets inside it + 1 hidden sheet. This needs to be sent to the master copy on the day of its' name, automatically if possible.
2) They can be made up to 3 months in advance and don't want it sending a blank back up daily.
3) When I press "backup" button on any newly created sheet I have to authorise the script.

Is there any way to not have to authorise the script on the new spreadsheet. Does anyone have a better idea for automating this?

```
    function onOpen() { // This function adds a custom menu to the spreadsheet (Backup to archive) so you can run the script from there.


var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Backup')
    .addItem('Backup','dataBackup')
    .addItem('Name','nameOfSpreadsheet')
    .addToUi();

 }
 function nameOfSpreadsheet() {
var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName().replace(/(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}).*/,'$1');
return s;
}

  function dataBackup() {
  var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {

    var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

    var date = inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // Changed to stop inadvertent cell changes, also made text white so not seen.
    var data = inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37').getValues().filter(function(row) { return row[0] !== '' || row[1] !== ''});

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        data[x].splice(0, 0, date);
    }
    var getDate = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
    var maxRowLength = data.reduce(function(length, row) { return Math.max(length, row.length); }, 0);
    var date = new Date(date); 

    if (date.getDate() === "Loading Data...") {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != date.getMonth()) {     

        if (data.length != 0) {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, maxRowLength).setValues(data);
        } else {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
       }}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to put `nameofSpreadsheet` in the menu `.addItem('Name','nameOfSpreadsheet')`.  It doesn't accomplish anything because there's no way to see the return.

I took a stab at rewriting your backup function.

```
function dataBackup() 
{
  var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
  var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
  for (var i=0; i<sheetNames.length; i++) 
  {
    var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var date=new Date(inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue());     
    var rng=inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37');
    var dataA=rng.getValues();
    var data=[];
    for(var j=0;i<dataA.length;j++)
    {
      if(dataA[j][0] && dataA[j][1])
      {
        data.push([dataA[j].splice(0,0,date)]);
      }
    }
    var dv=archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
    date=(typeof(dv)!='undefined')?dv:'No Date Found';
    if (data.length>0) 
    {
      archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
      archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, rng.getWidth()+1).setValues(data);
    } 
    else 
    {
      archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
      archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cooper, I removed the Name of spreadsheet in the menu.  Was something else I thought would work but didn't.  Thank you for the rewrite will copy and check it then get back to you.  Getting this error. any ideas?  TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 31, file "update backup data")  This is line 31 "      if(dataA[j][0] && dataA[j][1])
"